# send email to multiple recepients

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an e-mail to multiple e-mail address in my database. Here is my current code. It is only working when I specify a single e-mail address, however, I need to have them query my database and send the e-mail to each e-mail address. Where am I going wrong here?

```
    $elist = $database->getRows("SELECT * FROM `emails`");

    if ($elist) {
        foreach ($elist as $elist_result) {
            $frm = 'rdsyh@gmail.com';
            $sub = 'Weekly Work Report';
            ob_start(); // start output buffering
            include_once('mail_content.php');
            $mail_body = ob_get_contents(); // get the contents from the buffer
            ob_end_clean();
            $to = $elist_result['email'];
            $mailstatus = l_mail('', '', $to, $elist_result['firstname'] . ' ' . $elist_result['lastname'], $frm, 'HR', $sub, $mail_body);

        }
    }


if ($mailstatus == 'ok') {
    echo '<center><font color=red style="font-size:14px">Message has been sent Succesfully.....!</font></center><br>';
} else {
    echo $mailstatus;
}
```

Comment: Could the problem be with your query and loop? If you `echo $elist_result['email']` inside the loop, do you get the expected e-mail addresses?

Comment: yes.got all the expected email ids but mail was send to the first email address only

Comment: Well, without the code to l_mail(), there's no way to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a lot of abstraction here that we know nothing about from your code.  Things to check:

- Are you certain that your database query is returning all of the results you're looking for (is $elist populated properly)?
- Are you certain that the query is returning data in the format that you're trying to access it in (is $to populated properly)?
- Are you certain your l_mail() function is behaving (is it possible it `exit`'s or otherwise terminates script execution in the middle of the first pass)?

Based on what I see here, if everything else was working properly, you should successfully be sending a bunch of emails, one to each email in your list.

Now, if instead you're trying to send a single email that is sent to all of the addresses at once, then you need to group the email addresses in the for loop and then run your mail function afterwards:

```
<?
$tos = array();
foreach ($elist as $elist_result) {
    $tos[] = $elist_result['email'];
}
$frm = 'rdsyh@gmail.com';
$sub = 'Weekly Work Report';
ob_start(); // start output buffering
include_once('mail_content.php');
$mail_body = ob_get_contents(); // get the contents from the buffer
ob_end_clean();
$to = implode(', ', $tos);
$mailstatus = l_mail('', '', $to, $elist_result['firstname'] . ' ' . $elist_result['lastname'], $frm, 'HR', $sub, $mail_body);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What does l_mail() do? If its a web service, then it might have limit for mass emails.

Comment: I_mail is a PHPmailer class function